# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'select' does not exist in type 'Settings'

Tags: javascript, angular

when i try to write this javascript code in angular what did i miss ?

```
 ngOnInit() {


  $('#jithesh').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    } ],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
```

and this is the original java script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

trying to follow what is in this example

https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid jQuery with Angular if you can
2. Your element isn't in the DOM when you run the jQuery in `ngOnInit()`. Instead, move your code from `ngOnInit()` into `ngAfterViewInit()`.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mn2776

This demo shows you the result of a `document.getElementById('id').outerHTML` during the initial lifecycle hooks of the component:

- `ngOnInit()` - undefined
- `ngAfterContentInit()` - undefined
- `ngAfterViewInit()` - outerHTML

Code used:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.onInit = this.getOuterHtml();
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.afterContentInit = this.getOuterHtml();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.afterViewInit = this.getOuterHtml();
    })    
  }

  private getOuterHtml() {
    const el = document.getElementById('el');
    return el ? el.outerHTML : 'undefined';
  }
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Or even better, move the jquery code to a directive that wraps that functionality

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis baby steps! I think custom directive is a jump too far for an answer in this case.

Comment: i am naive in angular , still getting this error ERROR in src/app/all-in-one/all-in-one.component.ts(53,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ columnDefs: { orderable: false; className: string; targets: number; }[]; select: { style: string; selector: string; }; order: (string | number)[][]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'select' does not exist in type 'Settings'.

Comment: @JitheshChandra that doesn't sound related to your original question. Can you repeat my experiment in my stackblitz, but with `$('#jithesh')`.